# import sub-packages or module from directory of setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, packaging, setup.py

I started making a package (an executable in fact) and made a small program that contains several files in a directory structure:

```
my_app_proj
  |-setup.py
  |-my_app
     |-my_app.py
     |-__init__.py
     |-lib
        |-libA.py
        |-libB.py
```

In the file `my_prog.py`, I have something like:

```
from lib import libA
from lib import libB
```

But when I want to create my package with `setup.py`,the import directives are no longer operational because they are not in the PYTHONPATH.
Obviously since I am in the parent directory of the `my_prog` directory.

One solution is to add in the file `__init__.py` the path of `my_prog` in the python path, but I find it crappy.

Is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use relative import :

```
from .lib import libA
```